# CSS: Implementing Fixed Header scroll in a Table that contains multiple <tbody> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is the table structure that I have:

```
                <table>
                        <thead >
                            <tr>
                                <th >Header 1</th>
                                <th >Header 1</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Cell</td>
                                <td>Cell</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Cell</td>
                                <td>Cell</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have multiple tbody tags to support a nested ng-repeat structure with spanned rows hence it is inevitable to have the tbody tags.
However, I am now unable to put these tbody tags in a valid container and set the overflow-y as auto inorder to bring in the scroll bar just for the table data and not including the thead (headers)

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: make your headers fixed on the top, or make it fixed with 2 different tables: 1st with headings, second - with data

Comment: Two table is the simplest solution but there is a tremendous problem of alignment of column widths between the two tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first thing to consider of multiple tbody. you can do your task without using of multiple tbody as it is not a good approach.

Aside you can use [Table FloadHead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/)  plug in. probably it will help in making headers fixed.